# How can I ask Google and Bing bot to stop crawling this urls

Tags: search, bots, analytics

How I ask Google and bing bot to not crawl such urls? Some external site generated such links domain.com/search?q=????ggseo.com??? and I am logging the search parameter and found this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google might be just indexing those. This may indicate that your site had been hacked and doorway'd.

First, check your web server logs, comparing them to the analytics logs. See if they correspond.

Next, check indexed pages in google by using `site:your-site.com` See for inadequate results.

Next, change your useragent to googlebot and go to your site from an incognito browser. See if you can see more issues there.

If this doesn't turn out to be useful, then show more analytics screenshots, now including the dimension names. Show your data debugging better.